# Tailwind background image not showing

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

The background image is not showing. I also tried "bg-[url('/image/example.jpeg')"

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        darkBlue: "#0D1A32",
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        "hero-image": "url('/app/images/lentcm93p_1.jpg')",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**Page.js**

```js
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="h-[455px] w-full bg-hero-image bg-cover">
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Inspect the browser network events; what happens when the image is downloaded? If there's an error here, it's likely a path issue (or your file doesn't exist at all). If you have a baseURL setup, that's probably a factor here.

Comment: @MarsAndBack Thanks, i didn't have to include the '/app/' at the beginning of the url.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe file `/app/images/lentcm93p_1.jpg` doesn't exist on your project

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the wrong reference. Usually `/app` wouldn't be used.

Try changing

```
"hero-image": "url('/app/images/lentcm93p_1.jpg')",
```

to

```
"hero-image": "url('images/lentcm93p_1.jpg')",
```